# PHP - How to map multiple strings to single one? e.g. 'en','english','eng' --> 'eng'

Tags: php, dictionary, many-to-one

I want a many-to-one key->value mapping of strings.

My only idea so far is to do with a series of tests like this, but it's not very inelegant.

```
switch($s) {
    case "en":
    case "thatlanguagethebritsspeak":
    case "english":
        return "eng";
    ...
}
```

What would be a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$languages = array( 'en' =>array('english','eng','thatlanguagethebritsspeak'),'de'=>array('deutsch','german'));
// convert it to lowercase
$s= strtolower($s);
foreach ($languages as $code => $language){
     if(in_array($s,$language){
          $s = $code; 
          break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I like this solution as you can define the array statically.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(in_array($s,array("eng","en","english"))){
   //..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With regex, you can use case sensitive or not feature, which can be an advantages...

```
return (preg_match('/(en|eng|english)/i',$s)) ? 'eng' : 'default';
```